# File opens before printing?

Tags: java, printing

Hi m using this program to print my files bt it opens the file before printing?i want to remove that.any suggestions?

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class PrintFile {    

  public static void fileToPrint(File fis) {
    try {
      Desktop desktop = null;
      if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
      {

        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();  

      }   
       desktop.print(fis);  
       System.out.print("Printing Document");
    }
    catch (IOException ioe)
    {
      ioe.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Desktop API in AWT uses the native functionality of the system (in this case Windows.) The JVM is likely invoking ShellExecute/ShellExecuteEx on the file with the "print" command. The way Windows handles the command is to search the registry for the file type's print command, and run that. For most file types, this will result in the application that handles it opening, and then executing the print command automatically.

In short, I don't think you'll be able to use the Desktop API without having the applications open. You would need to do all the printing yourself (which, of course, is very difficult.)

Comment: will this Desktop API  run on a linux system also?

Comment: I'm not sure what method a linux JVM would use to print, though I imagine it would be similar. No matter what, the task will be delegated to the native system's method of printing a file, which will almost always involve starting the file-type's handler, since that's really the only application that knows how to print the file properly.